# Update cognito user pool with cdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-cdk

We are currently using aws amplify with cognito.

Our issue is whenever somebody sign up on our website, they receive an confirmation email where the "from" email is "no-reply@verificationemail.com". We want to change it.

The idea was to change it with CDK.

```
const cognitoUserPoolArn = cdk.Fn.ref(
  dependencies.auth.energycommunity.UserPoolArn
)

let userpool = cdk.aws_cognito.UserPool.fromUserPoolArn(
  this,
  'userpool',
  cognitoUserPoolArn
)

new cdk.aws_cognito.CfnUserPool(this, 'cognito_userpool', {
  emailConfiguration: {
    from: 'example@example.com',
    replyToEmailAddress: 'example@example.com',
  },
})
```

I am currently here but this is not what i wanted. the `cognitouserPoolArn` is the ARN of our cognito from our amplify app.

How can i update the "from" email with cdk?

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  The CDK can only modify resources that are part of a CDK app.

Some types of existing resources can be "imported" into a CDK app with the [cdk import](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/main/packages/aws-cdk/README.md#cdk-import) command.  The imported resource is then managed by the CDK and can be modified.  That would be ideal for you, but unfortunately a User Pool is not on the [list of importable resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import-supported-resources.html).

Methods like `fromFooArn` create a [read-only reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/resources.html) to an existing `Foo` resource.  It cannot be used to modify the Foo.  The `new cdk.aws_cognito.CfnUserPool` command creates a new resource.  Likewise, it can't be used to modify your exisitng User Pool.

The SDK can modify an existing User Pool's email confguration.   See the [UpdateUserPoolCommand](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/v3/latest/preview/client/cognito-identity-provider/command/UpdateUserPoolCommand/).